# Specified cast not valid

Tags: c#

Can someone help me with this... i just simply can't locate where the error is... cause even I entered the right username and password a message pops up saying specified cast not valid

```
if (user_txt.Text != "" & pass_txt.Text != "")
{
    string queryText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM stiguidancesample.users " + "WHERE username = @Username AND password = @Password";
    MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryText, cn);
    {
        cn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user_txt.Text);  // cmd is SqlCommand 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass_txt.Text);
        int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result > 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Loggen In!");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("User Not Found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message and where does it occur?

Comment: Is it the cast to `int` that's failing? If you debug through it but have `object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); int result = (int) o;` you can look at the *actual* type of `o` before the cast.

Comment: in the line of `int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: I think the `count()` method of MySQL returns a `long` and not an `int`. That would explain the error when you unbox the value.

Comment: @Dirk IIRC that is what's happening: `(int)o` fails if `o` is a boxed `long`. One possible fix is doing this: `(int)(long)o`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem :** hee you need to remember that you are performing implicit casting using below statement:

```
int result = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

the implicit casting only works if the value is valid integer.if it contains value like 10.0 or some spaces it wont work.

**Solution :** if you want to get the value in all of the caes you need to use
Explicit casting using `Convert.ToInt32()` method.

Try This:

```
   int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: This is an issue I run into a lot and the answer is a great help!